# Firebase get new AccessToken given by googleAuthProvider after it expires

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-apis-explorer

I'm writing React app hooked up to Firebase. My server on Flask validates accessToken via

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}
```

After 3600 sec my token expired, and I cannot validate myself through this query anymore ;(

After days of researching in the firebase docs, I haven't found any solution to refresh the accessToken with native methods. The token I get by calling `GoogleAuthProvider`, and saving `acceessToken` to localstorage in DOM. Like so:

```
const handleSignIn = (userCredential) => {
    const {accessToken} = userCredential.credential;
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

if (provider) {
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(handleSignIn)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

My access token starts with

> ya29.

This is used in my sign in logic. Now I'm trying to refresh `accessToken` without having to RE-authenticate a user.
I tried calling this query

```
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[my api key in firebase]&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[refresh token given by provider]
```

, but access token given in result doesn't starts with

> ya29.

and doesn't validates by calling the query I've mentioned earlier...

- How to handle refreshing `accessToken` given by firebase?
- Why a new access token given by *securetoken* query doesn't starts with ya29 and what is it for?

Comment: You can find your answer in this official doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Comment: @RishabhJain So as I understood from reading it.
1st - there is no way to obtain a newer accessToken on a client side only (Assuming it's referred as an `ID token` in docs, tell me if I'm wrong). 
2nd - I must manually (not silently) reauthentificate user after my server recognize his token is invalid (in example they use `prompt` to input user's password on client side)
I haven't tried that example, since I want `accessToken` (`ID token` [maybe]) to be renewed automatically, without user interaction whatsoever. Preferably on client side, if this is a proper logic to follow. 
Thanks :)

Comment: @VladislavKasintsev Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue as well

Comment: @InquisitiveTom, I have transitioned to firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true) every time I make a query to the server, and verify my token with firebase admin on server side. Not sure if that's correct approach, but this seems like on the options.